# using /usr/bin/script to record sessions, but readable .txt

Tags: logging, session

How can I get the /usr/bin/script files to be "readable" .txt ?

For example I'm recording sessions like:

```
script "/path/`date "+%y%m%d-%H%M%S-term-session.txt"`"
```

When I "more" the files they come back as "binary" and have "extra" characters that make them less user friendly.

Thanks,
Greg

Answer (score 0):

I found this

```
cat $SCRIPT_LOG_FILE | perl -pe 's/\e([^\[\]]|\[.*?[a-zA-Z]|\].*?\a)//g' | col -b > $txtfile
```

and it seems to work.

Credit was:
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+question/7131